# Php and OpenSsl

Tags: php, openssl, php-openssl

I should execute the following openssl command on a host server with the php support and the php-openssl extension enabled.

openssl.exe smime -verify -inform DER -in $p7m_file -noverify -out $out_file

What's the equivalent php code of the above (properly functioning) command ? I have to use only the openssl-extension and not any shell command.

In detail, I need to decrypt a CADES file without validating the signature
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAdES_(computing)

Comment: Did you try [openssl_pkcs7_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-verify.php)? It should work with `openssl_pkcs7_verify($infile, PKCS7_NOVERIFY, null, null, null, $out_file);`

Comment: I'll try it and I will be back tomorrow

Comment: the command returns true, but print out the following error 
"PHP Warning:  openssl_pkcs7_verify(): error opening the file, "

Comment: Same problem on Linux and Windows, I have also double checked the input file path

Comment: The error is:
error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file

Comment: It seems that the input file does not exist. Verify that the path is correct, and the file is readable

Comment: I have double checked the input file path name. File is 777..